# How can I get Mathematica to print ConjugateTranspose[c] as $c^{\dagger}$?

Tags: output-formatting

Is there some kind of pretty print option that I can use? I'm writing down a lot of matrix elements. They would print out much more concisely as $c^{\dagger}$ than as `ConjugateTranspose[c]`.

Comment: Take a look at `TraditionalForm` in order to show it like that in the output. In order to write it like that in input you can write esc ct esc.

Answer (score 4):

```
{ConjugateTranspose[c],ConjugateTranspose[c]^2} /. ConjugateTranspose[c]->SuperDagger[c]
```

gives:

[image]